# sed command not identifying exact word in a variable

Tags: shell, sed

I am trying to replace a word irrespective of it's case in a file using sed command as below:

```
sed -ie s/$tbl/$third_ele/gI $sql_file
```

where `$tbl` contains word S_ASSET and `$third_ele` contains table_01. This breaks when the file contains word S_ASSET_XA, the script replaces S_ASSET_XA to table_01_XA which i don't want. I need to match it exactly while replacing because i have another instance where S_ASSET_XA should be replaced with another word table_02.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: have you tried the \b word boundary after $tbl?

Comment: @ruud By introducing \b, none of the words are being replaced. I tried this `sed -ie s/$tbl\b/$third_ele/gI $sql_file` and `sed -ie s/"$tbl"\b/$third_ele/gI $sql_file`

Answer (score 0):

Use \b to mark a word boundary.
Since you run from the command line, the escape character has to be doubled, since the shell does its own interpolation before handing it to sed:

```
sed -ie s/$tbl\\b/$third_ele/gI $sql_file
```